# Python code that compares two files byte by byte

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, file

I wrote a Python (2.7) script that compares a file byte by byte. `filecmp` was not suitable for the application because it compares metadata as well. How can I improve this code?

```
def byte_comp(fname, fname2):
    """
        Compares two files byte by byte
        Returns True if the files match, false otherwise
    """
    read_size = 1048576 # Determined experimentally
    if os.path.getsize(fname) != os.path.getsize(fname2): # If two files do not have the same size, they cannot be same
        return False
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
        with open(fname2, "rb") as f2:
            count = 0 # Counts how many bytes have been read
            while count <= os.path.getsize(fname): # Loops until the whole file has been read
                if(f.read(read_size) != f2.read(read_size)): # If the chunk of the file is not the same, the function returns false
                    return False
                count += read_size
    return True # If the files are the same, it returns True
```

I would also appreciate help on how to make the function faster and less CPU intensive.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3? I'm asking because they offer different (buffered) byte I/O interfaces.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Python 2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Run this through a PEP8 linter. One thing that sticks out - two spaces before inline comments.
- Combine your withs: `with open(fname, 'rb') as f, open(fname2, 'rb') as f2`
- The count/increment/compare approach is awkward and a C smell. Instead of that, simply read until you get an empty array, which indicates an EOF.

"resource-intensive" depends on which resource. If you decrease your `read_size` you might save a little on memory, but on most system save for embedded ones this will be negligible and your buffer size is fine.

If your constraining resource is time/CPU occupation, you could potentially parallelize this by reading both files at once and periodically joining to compare buffers. This might actually be harmful for performance if it's a hard disc since switching between files is slow, but it might help if you have an SSD. Testing is the only good way to know for sure.

Depending on a few factors, it might be faster not to do simultaneous I/O at all, and instead to compute a checksum or hash for the first file, second file, then compare the two. This has the advantage of greatly reducing the number of actual comparisons, and doing I/O in a more serial manner, but has the disadvantage of not being able to early-fail in the middle of a file if a difference is found.

All of this aside: unless your files are on the order of GB, this is likely premature optimization and isn't worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks. I meant CPU-intensive as I have more than enough memory. I have a HDD so I won't parallelize it. While the files aren't large, there are a lot of files to compare.

Answer (score 11):

1. The code in the post calls [`os.path.getsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize) for each block read from the two files. This could be avoided by remembering the value in a local variable.
2. The code accumulates `count` in order to detect the end of the files being compared. But the [`read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.read) method will return an empty bytes object when the end of file is reached, so there is no need to maintain a count.

   If you look at the implementation of the `filecmp` module, you'll see that file comparison is [implemented like this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d4992dccfb52ef4c0f4f9417b3e18fd7bd56476b/Lib/filecmp.py#L73-L82):

   ```
   def _do_cmp(f1, f2):
       bufsize = BUFSIZE
       with open(f1, 'rb') as fp1, open(f2, 'rb') as fp2:
           while True:
               b1 = fp1.read(bufsize)
               b2 = fp2.read(bufsize)
               if b1 != b2:
                   return False
               if not b1:
                   return True
   ```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that was how `filecmp` implemented it. The documentation said something about checking `os.stat` and I didn't want that. I had problems with it always returning `False` even when I set `shallow=False`. I'll try using `filecmp` again.

Comment: The documentation is right — `filecmp.cmp` calls `os.stat` on the two files, and if the results are equal it then calls `_do_cmp`.

Comment: In fact the file may have no size at all (yet still contain a finite byte stream) if it happens to be a FIFO or a special character device.

Comment: @jakekimdsΨ Comparing `stat` output is much faster than resorting to byte-by-byte comparison. The faster a difference can be found between the files, the better.

Comment: @Alexander In my case, the metadata can change but I want them to still be considered the same file if the bytes are the same, which is why comparing stat seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @jakekimdsΨ Not all `stat` metadata is compared. Total size is the most important thing to check. If there's different, then the byte-for-byte comparison can be completely short circuited. Creation/modification dates and other stuff like that are ignored