# Comparing same-size files and reporting on the differences byte-by-byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I created a small Python utility to analyze multiple same-size files and report on the difference byte-by-byte (i.e. [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance), not [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).) I am planning to extend the capabilities to allow a GUI display. Mostly, I'm interested in scalability and usability, with efficiency still being a high priority. I've already examined [Python code that compares two files byte by byte](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/171003/python-code-that-compares-two-files-byte-by-byte) and [other similar questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+file+differences), but none seem to involve the same type of analysis for the purpose of reporting on differences.

Specifically, I'm interested in two details:

1. Is there anything else I should consider in my `Difference` container structure and its handling?
2. Are there any downsides to my frequent use of generators? I tried to let it cycle through each difference via generator, minimizing memory usage, but I think that also has a few performance implications.

---

```
import os
import os.path
from enum import IntEnum
from collections import defaultdict

def compare_iterator_elements(lst, f=lambda x: x):
    '''Returns true if all the elements of an iterator are true, else returns false.'''
    try:
        first = f(next(lst))
        for i in lst:
            if first != f(i):
                return False
        return True
    except StopIteration:
        return True

# Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464
def chunks(l, n):
    '''Yield successive n-sized chunks from l. If len(l) is not divisible by n, the last chunk will be len(l) % n sized.'''
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

class Settings:
    '''Container class for difference formatting options.'''
    class Separation(IntEnum):
        CLUMPED = 0
        WIDTH_BROKEN = 1
        BLOCK_SEPARATED = 2
    separation = Separation.BLOCK_SEPARATED
    block_width = 0x10
# Planned future settings:
    # byte_group = 1
    # big_endian_groups = True
    # align_offset = 0

class Difference():
    '''Dictionary wrapper representing the difference at a specific point in a file.'''
    def __init__(self, difference, start):
        self.difference = difference
        self.start = start

    def extend(self, other):
        if other.start < self.start:
            raise ValueError(f'Differences can only be extended to differences with larger start values ({other.start} < {other.start}).')
        blank_width = other.start - (self.start + len(self))
        if blank_width < 0:
            raise ValueError(f'Extending to an overlapping Difference is not allowed.')
        for file, v in self.difference.items():
            v += ['  '] * blank_width + other.difference[file]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(next(iter(self.difference.values())))

    def __getitem__(self, value):
        difference = {k: v[value] for k,v in self.difference.items()}
        if isinstance(value, slice):
            return Difference(difference, self.start + (value.start if value.start else 0))
        else:
            return Difference(difference, self.start + value)

def _cli_difference(differences, start, settings):
    '''Outputs a difference in the command line.'''
    name_width = settings.name_width
    start_display = hex(start)[:-1] + 'X' if settings.separation > settings.Separation.CLUMPED else hex(start)
    print(f'{start_display.rjust(name_width)}:', end='')
    if settings.separation > settings.Separation.CLUMPED:
        print(' ' + ''.join((f' {i:x}' for i in range(settings.block_width))), end='')
    print()
    offset = start % settings.block_width
    for file_name, b in differences.items():
        print(f'{file_name.rjust(name_width)}: ', end='')
        if settings.separation > settings.Separation.CLUMPED:
            print('  ' * offset,
                  ''.join(b[:settings.block_width - offset]),
                  sep='', end='')
            for line in chunks(b[settings.block_width - offset:], settings.block_width):
                print('\n', ' ' * (name_width + 2), *line, sep='', end='')
            print()
        else:
            print(''.join(b))
    print()

def _separate_line_by_line(differences, settings):
    '''Generator function that separates and combines differences into fixed width blocks.'''
    current = next(differences)
    try:
        while True:
            offset = current.start % settings.block_width
            if offset + len(current) > settings.block_width:
                next_block = settings.block_width - offset
                yield current[:next_block]
                current = current[next_block:]
            else:
                next_diff = next(differences)
                block_start = current.start - offset
                if next_diff.start in range(block_start, block_start+settings.block_width):
                    current.extend(next_diff)
                else:
                    yield current
                    current = next_diff
    except StopIteration:
        yield current

def report_cli_differences(differences, settings):
    '''Outputs an iterable of differences in the command line.'''
    print('Differences:\n')
    if settings.separation == Settings.Separation.BLOCK_SEPARATED:
        differences = _separate_line_by_line(differences, settings)
    for diff in differences:
        _cli_difference(diff.difference, diff.start, settings)
    print('End of differences.')

def compare_files(file_args, difference_mask):
    '''Generator function that returns Difference objects for each aligned difference in same size files.'''
    if not compare_iterator_elements(iter(file_args), os.path.getsize):
        raise ValueError('The file sizes must be equal.')
    files = [open(file_name, 'rb') for file_name in file_args]
    while True:
        comparison = {f.name: f.read(1) for f in files}
        if not list(comparison.values())[0]:
            break
        bytes_different = lambda: not compare_iterator_elements(iter(comparison.values())) and compare_iterator_elements((comparison[file_name] for file_name in difference_mask))
        if bytes_different():
            start = files[0].tell()
            different_bytes = defaultdict(list)
            while True:
                for file_name, b in comparison.items():
                    different_bytes[file_name].append(f'{ord(b):0>2x}')
                comparison = {f.name: f.read(1) for f in files}
                if not bytes_different():
                    break
            yield Difference(different_bytes, start)
    for f in files:
        f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse
    arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Compares two files for differences.')
    arg_parser.add_argument('files', metavar='files', nargs='+', default=[f for f in os.listdir() if os.path.isfile(f)], help='file names to compare')
    arg_parser.add_argument('--separation', default=2, type = int, help='Specifies the level of difference separation. 0 is no separation, 1 is carriage returns after every block, and 2 separates every new block into a new comparison.')
    arg_parser.add_argument('--ignored_diff', metavar='FILES', nargs='+', help='For the purpose of reporting on differences, ignore the positions where differences occur between the given files.', default=[])
    args = arg_parser.parse_args()
    file_args = args.files
    settings = Settings()
    settings.separation = Settings.Separation(args.separation)
    ignore_differences = args.ignored_diff
    settings.name_width = max(len(str(os.path.getsize(file_args[0]))),
        *(len(file_name) for file_name in file_args))
    report_cli_differences(compare_files(file_args, 
                                         ignore_differences), settings)
```